# How to gather several values from different subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to get some statistics from several tables:

I have workers, orders and appointments.

How can it be done in one query:

```
1. SELECT count(id) AS TotalWorkers FROM workers;
2. SELECT w.name AS BestWorker FROM orders AS o LEFT JOIN workers AS w ON pe_id=w.id GROUP BY pe_id ORDER BY count(o.id) DESC LIMIT 1
3. SELECT count(id) AS OrdersPerformed FROM orders WHERE pe_id=1;
4. SELECT count(id) AS OrdersAccepted FROM orders WHERE ac_id=1;
5. SELECT post AS LastAppointment FROM appointments AS a LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON post_id=p.id WHERE worker_id=1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

How to gather them to be one big query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple method is to put `select` in front:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(id) FROM workers) AS TotalWorkers,
       (SELECT w.name FROM orders AS o LEFT JOIN workers AS w ON pe_id=w.id GROUP BY pe_id ORDER BY count(o.id) DESC LIMIT 1) as BestWorker,
       . . .
```